# If $X$ is a Tychonoff space, and has a base of clopen sets, then $X$ is normal?

Tags: general-topology

I´m trying find an counter example, but thefact that $X$ is a Tychonoff space let me think maybe $X$ is normal.

I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) is a counterexample. Let $X$ be the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology), i.e., $\Bbb R$ with the lower-limit topology that has the sets of the form $[a,b)$ as a base. $X$ is perfectly normal, hence Tikhonov, so its square $X^2$ is Tikhonov, but it is well-known that $X^2$ is not normal. For example, the closed sets $\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in\Bbb Q\}$ and $\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\}$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets; this is a consequence of the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 2):

No, e.g. Mrówka $\Psi$-space is completely regular, has a clopen base, is pseudocompact, separable, first countable, but not normal. (see [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/) for a description and proofs can be found on that site too.)

A more elementary but uglier example is $\Bbb N^I$ where $I$ is uncountable and $\Bbb N$ discrete, in the product topology. This is easily seen to have a clopen base and to be completely regular (productive properties) but an uncountable product of infinite discrete spaces is not normal (due to Stone; it's an exercise in Munkres, and a theorem in Engelking), or look [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/the-uncountable-product-of-the-countable-discrete-space-is-not-normal/), e.g.